# VB.NET Linq query Left outer join left is null

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use a linq query similar to this in SQL:

```
SELECT pos.*, cl.cltyp_level FROM TPSTAFFPOS pos LEFT OUTER JOIN TSTAFFCLTYP cl ON pos.pos_cllvlid = cl.cltyp_id
```

I have tried a few things.

```
Dim query = (From pos In TaRRDataSet.TPSTAFFPOS
             Join cl In TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFCLTYP
             On pos.pos_cllvlid Equals cl.cltyp_id
             Where pos.pos_id.Equals(CInt(text))
             Select cl.cltyp_level, pos).Distinct.ToArray
```

I have also tried group join:

```
Dim query = (From pos In TaRRDataSet.TPSTAFFPOS
             Group Join cl In TaRRDataSet.TSTAFFCLTYP
             On pos.pos_cllvlid Equals cl.cltyp_id Into cc = Group
             From cl In cc.DefaultIfEmpty()
             Select cl.cltyp_level, pos).Distinct.ToArray
```

The problem is the pos.pos_cllvlid could be null.  The cl table is just a lookup table.  The field in pos can be NULL.  How do i select the pos rows even if the pos.pos_cllvlid is null.  I searched and found the group join, but i still get the value is dbnull.  Here is an example of the data:

TPSTAFFPOS

```
| pos_id | pos_name   | pos_cllvlid |
|--------|------------|-------------|
| 1      | Position 1 | 1           |
| 2      | Position 2 | NULL        |
| 3      | Position 3 | 2           |
```

TSTAFFCLTYP

```
| cltyp_id | cltype_value |
|----------|--------------|
| 1        | TS           |
| 2        | S            |
| 3        | I            |
```

RESULT

```
| pos_id | pos_name   | pos_cllvlid | cltyp_value |
|--------|------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1      | Position 1 | 1           | TS          |
| 2      | Position 2 |             |             |
| 3      | Position 3 | 2           | S           |
```

As you can see in TPSTAFFPOS, the pos_cllvlid can be null.  Everything I try i keep getting the same error, "The value for column 'pos_cllvlid' in table TPSTAFFPOS is dbnull."

Comment: Group Join is correct. What do you mean by "i still get the value is dbnull"? Which "value"?

Comment: i get "The value for column 'pos_cllvlid' in table TPSTAFFPOS is dbnull.

Comment: The value in the main table TPSTAFFPOS for cllvlid can be null, so when it is trying to find the lookup value that is null, it errors out with the error above.

Comment: `DbNull` isn't the same as `null`. Make sure `cllvlid` is really null, not dbnull.

Comment: In my database the field has NULL

Comment: @GertArnold In the database it is NULL.  what do i do?

Comment: @GertArnold so this is for a lookup table.  the left table has pos_id which is the primary key for the table, in that same table is pos_cllvlid with a foreign key in the TSTAFFCLTYP table.  The issue is if the pos_cllvlid is null.  I can't figure out why the dbnull error.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `pos_cllvlid` field can hold `null` value, your final `Select` statement within `Group Join` should looks like:

```
        Select New With _
        {
            pos.pos_id,  _
            pos.pos_name,  _
            pos.pos_cllvlid,  _
            cl?.cltype_value
        }) _
         .Distinct() _
         .ToArray()
```

or

```
        Select pos, cl?.cltype_value) _
         .Distinct() _
         .ToArray()
```

As you can see, i've used `?` to prevent `NullReferenceException`. Left outer join is getting all data on left and when there's no related data returns `null` (`Nothing`) on right. So, before you'll try to access data on right, you have to check for `null` (`Nothing`).

As MSDN states, a `?` operator ...

> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null (Nothing) before
>   performing a member access (?.) or index (?()) operation; returns
>   Nothing if the left-hand operand evaluates to Nothing. Note that in
>   expressions that ordinarily return value types, the null-conditional
>   operator returns a Nullable.

For further details, please see: [?. and ?() null-conditional operators (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators)

Comment: When i put ? in, It says "The '?' character cannot be used here"

Comment: Try this: `Dim query = (From pos In staffposes Group Join cl In cltypes On pos.pos_cllvlid Equals cl.cltyp_id Into cc = Group From ccc In cc.DefaultIfEmpty()
 Select New With {pos, .ClValue = If(ccc Is Nothing, "NULL", ccc.cltype_value)}) _
 .Distinct() _
 .ToArray()`